# What does "basis points" mean in this context?

Tags: financial-literacy, economics, terminology

I read this sentence:

> Egypt's central bank cut its benchmark overnight deposit rate by
>   another 50 basis points to 8.75 percent, its second rate cut in two
>   months.

What does basis points mean in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point) has the definition of 1/100th of a percentage point.

So, 8.75 percent is 875 basis points for one example.  A quarter of one percent would be 25 basis points for another example.

Answer (score 6):

1 basis point is 0.01%, so 50 basis points would be 0.50%.

So Egypt's central bank cut its benchmark overnight deposit rate from 9.25% to 8.75%.